# What Facebook/iPhone game is this from?

Tags: ios, game-identification

From what I remember, the game is 3.5/4 years old and I think it was either an iPod/iPhone game or I played it through Facebook. It's basically like all the other monster collecting/fighting/training games but they could have different attributes.

I have tried a reverse image search but with no luck. I also looked through recommended games of popular games which are similar like [Mino Monsters](http://www.minomonsters.com/).

[image: One of the monsters I had.]

Comment: Tried to find something but nothing I found came close to this. If the text wasn't cut off it might be easier to find.

Comment: The image has words in it that looks like a name, you should have searched for those words.  The top result for the words "storm n" points to [this](http://forums.storm8.com/showthread.php?59747-Spirit-Dragon!-%28Crafting-IOS%29REMOVED/page20) which suggests it's [Dragon Story](http://www.storm8.com/game/dragon-story/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but some games like Mino Monsters for the iPhone include:

*Monster Galaxy

*Mighty Monsters

*GeoSociety

*Zenforms:Protectors

*Beastie Bay

*Hunter Island

I attempted searching for "games like Mino Monsters" and "games like Pokemon for iPhone" (since this looks like a Pokemon -like game), and these are a few of the results I found.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it kinda looks like it's Monster Galaxy.